# Record a scenario when server is at remote using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm asked to record the scenario of a website with a remote server(Linux Machine).

The scenario is been created in Windows machine and the Jmeter is running in the Linux Machine using record and playback option.

I have set the proxy in the Linux machine and tried recording the actions created in the Windows Machine,but it failed to record the actions when checked  the Linux Machine.

Has anyone tried such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be a problem given you can reach out to the Linux machine from the Windows machine.

Example setup:

1. On a Linux machine prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File - Templates - Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click `Start`
2. Copy `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file from Linux machine to the Windows machine
3. Import the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file into your browser
4. Configure your browser to use the Linux machine as the proxy, use it's hostname or IP address as the proxy host and `8888` as the proxy port. Additionally make sure that proxy is applied to all protocols and there are no exclusions (or at least your Linux host is not among them)

   [image]

See [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) guide for more information if needed

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer...It made my day

Answer (score 0):

You can either check on some local linux machine first if available or try [BlazeMeter Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) if you are new to Jmeter script recording, it is free on your remote linux machine.